# Solve a summation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

Hi guys I have an exercise I don't know how to approach, would be cool if you could give me a tip or two!
 A sequence $a_{n}$ is defined by a dependency :
 $$ \sum_{i, j, k \geq 0}^{i+j+k = n } a_ia_ja_k = (n+1)^{\overline{5}} \text {    
      for  $n\geq$ 0}$$
I am to solve the given summation and find an equation for $a_{n}$.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you messed up with the latex. Please look into it and post the correct expression.

Comment: It should be added that we do appreciate the fact that you took the time to try formatting your question!

Comment: Could you let us know what $\overline{5}$ represents? I see it formatted as an exponent, but it's not clear what it denotes.

Comment: @amWhy My guess would be that it means the rising factorial, i.e.: $$(n+1)^{\overline{5}}=(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)$$

Comment: Yes, its a rising factorial as seen in Concrete Mathematics

Comment: Yes, that makes sense...thanks for clarifying, darenn and @Shaktal

Answer (score 5):

Clearly

$$\sum_{n\ge 0}(n+1)^{\overline 5}x^n=D^5\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n=D^5\left(\frac1{1-x}\right)=\frac{5!}{(1-x)^6}\;.$$

As vonbrand already pointed out,

$$\sum_{i, j, k \geq 0}^{i+j+k = n } a_ia_ja_k$$

is the coefficient of $x^n$ in

$$\left(\sum_{k\ge 0}a_kx^k\right)^3\;,$$

so

$$\left(\sum_{k\ge 0}a_kx^k\right)^3=\frac{5!}{(1-x)^6}\;,$$

and

$$\sum_{k\ge 0}a_kx^k=\frac{5!^{1/3}}{(1-x)^2}=2\sqrt[3]{15}\sum_{k\ge 0}(k+1)x^k\;.$$

Comment: I.e., $a_k = 2 \sqrt[3]{15} (k + 1)$

Comment: @vonbrand: Yep; I thought that I’d leave a *little* for the OP to do.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: @vonbrand: Not to worry: I was half joking anyway.

Answer (score 1):

That looks suspiciously like a 3-way convolution...
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_n (n + 1)^{\overline{5}} z^n &= \sum_{i + j + k = n} a_i a_j a_k z^n \\
                                  &= \left( \sum_k a_k z^k \right)^3
\end{align*}
$$
The polynomial in $n$ can be handled by $p(x D) \dfrac{1}{1 - x}$, where the operator $x D = x \dfrac{d}{d x}$. Unless something spectacular happens, the cubic root will be a veritable mess.

Comment: As it says in [the cartoon](http://star.psy.ohio-state.edu/coglab/Miracle.html), a miracle occurs. :-)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, nice solution. It bugs me that I didn't see that...